# Appropriate oil viscosity for the inside of a freewheel body

Tags: freewheel, lubricant

Without taking one apart, I have seen people spraying WD40 into a freewheel body to clear it out, and then dripping Phil's tenacious oil into it for lubrication. The thickest stuff I have available at the moment is wet-weather chain lube. Will this work or destroy the freewheel? How important is viscosity here?

Comment: Proper maintenance can only be done by taking the freewheel/freehub apart which may sometimes be arduous. For specifications about lubricants you should always refer to the manufacturer. You'll find many related videos on the Net. The WD40 etc procedure will probably do more damage than good as chainlube will stiffen and the freewheel may stop working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The only freehub-specific lube I have found is from Dumonde Tech. They offer a freehub lube in both oil and grease form; depending on your preference. Those are what I use when servicing my rear wheels. Cleaning with WD-40 isn't bad practice as it's just a water displacement solution (Thus the "WD") and only imparts a very, very light lube to whatever surface it covers. I use it for cleaning bike and motorcycle parts all the time and to add some protective covering to parts with exposed raw metal.